# Formula/algorithm/train of thought for USACO Training Question(Wormholes from 2013)?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math, combinations

This is the description on the USACO website:

Farmer John's hobby of conducting high-energy physics experiments on weekends has backfired, causing $N$ wormholes ($2 \le N \le 12, N$ even) to materialize on his farm, each located at a distinct point on the 2D map of his farm (the $x,y$ coordinates are both integers).

According to his calculations, Farmer John knows that his wormholes will form $N/2$ connected pairs. For example, if wormholes $A$ and $B$ are connected as a pair, then any object entering wormhole $A$ will exit wormhole B moving in the same direction, and any object entering wormhole $B$ will similarly exit from wormhole $A$ moving in the same direction. This can have rather unpleasant consequences.

For example, suppose there are two paired wormholes $A$ at $(1,1)$ and $B$ at $(3,1)$, and that Bessie the cow starts from position $(2,1)$ moving in the $+x$ direction. Bessie will enter wormhole $B$ [at $(3,1)$], exit from $A$ [at $(1,1)$], then enter $B$ again, and so on, getting trapped in an infinite cycle!

Farmer John knows the exact location of each wormhole on his farm. He knows that Bessie the cow always walks in the $+x$ direction, although he does not remember where Bessie is currently located.

Please help Farmer John count the number of distinct pairings of the wormholes such that Bessie could possibly get trapped in an infinite cycle if she starts from an unlucky position. FJ doesn't know which wormhole pairs with any other wormhole, so find all the possibilities.

I can find every combination of pairing between the wormholes, but I am having trouble finding some of the infinite loop combinations. I can find all of these combinations when there is only one pair of wormholes with the same $y-$coordinate, as I just connect those, and then find the number of possibilities for pairs to form for the rest of the wormholes. I can also find the total number of combinations when there are three wormholes with the same $y-$coordinate, and the rest all have their own unique $y-$coordinate. But I'm not really sure about what algorithm I can implement when there is more than one pair with the same $y-$coordinates.

Any ideas?

Comment: I looked it up to double-check, but it would be good to clarify that this is a problem from 2013 and not from an ongoing contest: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=360

Comment: $12$ is small enough that you could generate every possible paring and test each one to see if there is a loop. (There are only $\frac{12!}{2^6 6!} = 10395$ pairings of $12$ objects.) You can test if there is a loop by placing the cow at any of the wormholes, and seeing if it enters a loop when starting at that wormhole. I'd pre-compute the wormhole closest to the right of each wormhole. e.g. By sorting each row. There are probably better ways to do it, but we're dealing with very small input so we don't have to be that careful.